# Shell "set" command in Linux and MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, sh

I have stumbled upon this small difference between the `set` implementation of the 2 operating systems.

When running:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

echo "${@}"
```

Running this on MacOS gives the following error:

> @: unbound variable

Whereas running this in a Linux environment, results no errors, but echos an empty string.

Can this be resolved somehow, except changing `${@}` to `${@:-}` as this may result different results, if the amount of arguments is checked within the code.

Comment: Are you passing arguments to the script in either cases?

Comment: For both cases, I am not passing any arguments.

Comment: execute `readlink -f /bin/sh` on your Mac and on your Linux and print the output into your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell you have on Linux conforms to the latest POSIX standard while the one on MacOS does not (see [spec.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25_03), scroll downwards for **-u**; related: [#0000155](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=155)), hence the difference in behavior. A workaround would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu
echo "${1+"$@"}"
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `${1+"$@}"}`? Otherwise, if `$1` is set, only `$1` is printed. With `+`, if `$1` is set, `$@` is printed.

Comment: I really like this `echo "${1+"$@"}"`. Nicely thought :)

Comment: @Benjamin yeah you're right, I missed that, thank you

Comment: Why `"${1+"$@"}"`, not `"$@"` ?

Comment: @Philippe There is no difference between `$@` and `${@}`, do you know of a sh implementation that treats these two differently?

Comment: There IS a difference. If OP replace "${@}" by "$@", he would not have the error.

Comment: @Philippe I think there is not, otherwise he would have accepted your answer.

Comment: Let's wait for OP to confirm.

Comment: @Philippe Ok, can you at least provide a document or something that says removing enclosing braces will fix OP's issue?

Comment: I tested on my Catalina/macos. If you don't have macos, download http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.2.57.tar.gz, compile and test.

Comment: @Philippe thanks, that's a bug specific to a version then. My answer covers hypothetical shells that misinterpreted the earlier versions of the standard, as well as that buggy version of bash

Answer (score 0):

As you have an old version of bash on macos, you have to use "$@"

You can check the version with :

```
/bin/sh --version
```

Comment: `/bin/sh --version` is not always working. On my Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a soft link to `/bin/dash` and `/bin/dash --version` is illegal.

Comment: Agree. I mean that on macos you must have `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)`